# Pictures inserted on some computers are not clear

Tags: eyeshot

I insert the picture into the eyeshot. The inserted picture is as clear as the source picture, but on a few computers, the picture will become particularly blurred. I send the customer's system information to see if it is helpful to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot!

> [system info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfiKB.png) [source picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZlh4.png) [piture in eyeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3jeT.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the graphics adapter drivers and update them to the latest version available.

The system info you provided does not include data from the graphics adapter.

Comment: The driver is the latest, but the picture is not clear yet.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKIWq.jpg

Comment: Is the picture resolution good enough? Can you attach the raster image in your OP?

Comment: sure, the picture resolution is very good,  I have attached the source picture file in the question。

Answer (score 0):

The driver is the latest, but the picture is not clear yet.

[image: The information of graphics adapter]